# How to resolve memory leak issue of a string declared globally in an NSObject class and used somewhere else

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, instruments

In my iPhone app I have a `NSObject` class 'Contact' in that I have a string like this

```
@interface Contact : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
```

---

```
@implementation Contact

@synthesize name;
```

and I used this name string in some other class (in Sqlite methods) as follows

```
  Contact *contact = [[[Contact alloc] init] autorelease];

   contact.name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char*) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
```

when I run using instruments I have some memory warnings at

```
contact.name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char*) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
```

I have so many leaks like this.. how to resolve this issue..

Comment: have you implemented the `dealloc` method in your model class?

Comment: yes i used it relese them in unload

Comment: you need to add a dealloc method in your `Contact` class.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with the code that you've shown, *unless* you didn't properly implement the `dealloc` method in your `Contact` class.

It should be something like this (Contact.m):

```
-(void) dealloc {
   [name release];
   [super dealloc];
}
```

I can't tell what you mean by your comment

> yes i used it relese them in unload

If all you're doing is releasing the `Contact` object in a view controller's `viewDidUnload` method, that's not enough.

However, I'll take the opportunity to say that [ARC has been available for a while now](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html), and almost everybody who's not an expert (and most of the experts, too) *should* be using ARC, instead of manual memory management like this.

It really saves a lot of these time-consuming debugging exercises, and if your problem *was* this `dealloc` issue, then ARC would have solved that for you.

Comment: +1 I think you have it, however I still use MRR and actually think it's *easier* to understand provided you understand the rules of memory management under Objective-C.  It also means you can support 32-bit Mac runtimes as well...

Comment: That's a **gigantic** *if* (understanding the rules).  Most developers vastly overestimate their ability to catch these kinds of problems.  It's also an issue of how much time even a good developer spends getting reference counting right, and auditing it, and the opportunity cost of that.  How much good code could you have written in that time, that provides features that users will actually notice?  I'll also add that on memory-constrained, embedded devices, I think avoiding leaks is even more important than on desktops ... and this was an iOS question.